# How to use Jquery Validation Engine to validate CLEditor (html editor) inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysiwyg, jquery-validation-engine, cleditor

How do I use the [jquery.validationEngine](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine) plugin to validate [CLEditor](http://premiumsoftware.net/CLEditor/GettingStarted) wysiwyg editor inputs?  I am trying to validate an html editor input on form submission using the specific jquery plug-ins referenced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution that I came up with.  You can also get a copy from [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/WXaE5bA9)

<-- PLEASE, vote if it was helpful.

```
    // Include all the jquery, jquery ui, cleditor, and validation-engine CSS and javascript library files here


    <script type="text/javascript">

    // object used to store the validation states of any html editor textarea inputs used on the page
    var editorStates = new Object();

    // add one property/value for each textarea id that you are using on this page..
    // in this example there are going to be three diferent editor inputs:
    editorStates['your_textarea_id_1']=true; 
    editorStates['your_textarea_id_2']=true;
    editorStates['your_textarea_id_etc']=true;


    $(document).ready(function(){


        // ==========================================================================
        // initialize the cleditor object(s) for the textarea(s) used on this page...
        // ==========================================================================

            // initialize the 'your_textarea_id_1' textarea and store the cleditor object in the 'your_textarea_id_1_editor' variable...  
            var your_textarea_id_1_editor = $("#your_textarea_id_1").cleditor({
                width:        650, // width not including margins, borders or padding
                height:       220, // height not including margins, borders or padding
                controls:     // controls to add to the toolbar
                "bold italic underline | font size " +
                "style | color highlight removeformat | bullets numbering | outdent " +
                "indent | alignleft center alignright justify | pastetext source",
            }).change(function (){
                if(editorStates['your_textarea_id_1']==false){ // input has been validated as false so need to check it as user types so the flag goes away when appropriate...
                    valid_editor_text('your_textarea_id_1'); // re-validate this input
                };
            });

            // initialize the 'your_textarea_id_2' textarea and store the cleditor object in the 'your_textarea_id_2_editor' variable...  
            var your_textarea_id_2_editor = $("#your_textarea_id_2").cleditor({
                width:        650, // width not including margins, borders or padding
                height:       220, // height not including margins, borders or padding
                controls:     // controls to add to the toolbar
                "bold italic underline | font size " +
                "style | color highlight removeformat | bullets numbering | outdent " +
                "indent | alignleft center alignright justify | pastetext source",
            }).change(function (){
                if(editorStates['your_textarea_id_2']==false){ // input has been validated as false so need to check it as user types so the flag goes away when appropriate...
                    valid_editor_text('your_textarea_id_2'); // re-validate this input
                };
            });

            // initialize the 'your_textarea_id_etc' textarea and store the cleditor object in the 'your_textarea_id_etc_editor' variable...  
            var your_textarea_id_etc_editor = $("#your_textarea_id_etc").cleditor({
                width:        650, // width not including margins, borders or padding
                height:       220, // height not including margins, borders or padding
                controls:     // controls to add to the toolbar
                "bold italic underline | font size " +
                "style | color highlight removeformat | bullets numbering | outdent " +
                "indent | alignleft center alignright justify | pastetext source",
            }).change(function (){
                if(editorStates['your_textarea_id_etc']==false){ // input has been validated as false so need to check it as user types so the flag goes away when appropriate...
                    valid_editor_text('your_textarea_id_etc'); // re-validate this input
                };
            });

        // ==========================================================================
        // initialize the jquery validation-engine
        // ==========================================================================

            // Note: 'mainform' is the id value of the form element that contains the three textarea inputs
            //       Replace this with the id value of YOUR form id!
            jQuery("#mainform").validationEngine('attach', {
                onValidationComplete: function(form, status){

                        // Note: 'status' will already be true/false based on the validation results of any other inputs that you
                        //       are validating using the typical validation methods provided by the validationEngine plugin.

                        // Now we need to validate the textarea (cleditor html editor) inputs...

                        //  validate the 'your_textarea_id_1' textarea input
                        if( your_textarea_id_1_editor[0].sourceMode() == false ){
                            // in editor mode, need to update the hidden textarea input
                            your_textarea_id_1_editor[0].updateTextArea();
                        }
                        if(! valid_editor_text('your_textarea_id_1') ){ // <-- pass the textarea id value to the 'valid_editor_text' function
                            // The validation on this input failed...
                            status=false; // prevent the form from submitting
                        }

                        //  validate the 'your_textarea_id_2' textarea input
                        if( your_textarea_id_2_editor[0].sourceMode() == false ){
                            // in editor mode, need to update the hidden textarea input
                            your_textarea_id_2_editor[0].updateTextArea();
                        }
                        if(! valid_editor_text('your_textarea_id_2') ){ // <-- pass the textarea id value to the 'valid_editor_text' function
                            // The validation on this input failed...
                            status=false; // prevent the form from submitting
                        }

                        //  validate the 'your_textarea_id_etc' textarea input
                        if( your_textarea_id_etc_editor[0].sourceMode() == false ){
                            // in editor mode, need to update the hidden textarea input
                            your_textarea_id_etc_editor[0].updateTextArea();
                        }
                        if(! valid_editor_text('your_textarea_id_etc') ){ // <-- pass the textarea id value to the 'valid_editor_text' function
                            // The validation on this input failed...
                            status=false; // prevent the form from submitting
                        }


                        // submit if there are no validation errors
                        if(status == true){
                            form.validationEngine('detach'); // prevents an endless loop
                            form.submit(); // form is valid, now submit it
                        }


                }
            });


    }); // end doc ready


    // ============================================================================
    // The 'valid_editor_text' function
    // This function does the actual validation of the textarea (html editor) input 
    // ============================================================================
        function valid_editor_text(inputID){        


            str = $('#'+inputID).val();

            // Note: str contains the value of the textarea input so do whatever validations you need
            //       against that.  Return true if it's valid or false if it isn't.


            // Right now I am just checking to make sure that the user entered anything at all ...

            // remove any <br>, <br />, &nbsp;, {spaces}, and/or {newlines} from the beginning of the string
            // just to make sure the user typed some actual text instead of random spaces and enter keys (aka nothing)
            str = str.replace(/^(?:<[Bb][Rr](?: \/)?>|\&[Nn][Bb][Ss][Pp];|\n| )+/g,'');
            if(str.length > 0){
                console.log("valid_editor_text('"+inputID+"')"+' returning true');
                editorStates[inputID]=true;
                // hide any previous prompts on this input
                $('#'+inputID+'_prompt_location').validationEngine('hide');
                return true;
            }else{
                console.log("valid_editor_text('"+inputID+"')"+' returning false');
                editorStates[inputID]=false;
                // need to display the validation message for this input
                $('#'+inputID+'_prompt_location').validationEngine('showPrompt', 'This field is required.', 'required', 'topRight', true);
                return false;
            }
        }

    </script>


</head>
<body>


<form action="youraction.goes.here" method="post" name="mainform" id="mainform">


<!-- Add a placeholder div that is used to target the position of a validation message if the validation fails
     The id value is the value of your textarea id with '_prompt_location' appended, like so.. -->
<div>     
<div id="your_textarea_id_1_prompt_location"></div>

<!-- Finally, the textarea input that is causing all this fuss .. -->
<textarea id="your_textarea_id_1" name="your_textarea_id_1"></textarea>
</div>

<!-- repeat for the other textareas you are using .. -->
<div>
<div id="your_textarea_id_2_prompt_location"></div>
<textarea id="your_textarea_id_2" name="your_textarea_id_2"></textarea>
</div>

<div>
<div id="your_textarea_id_etc_prompt_location"></div>
<textarea id="your_textarea_id_etc" name="your_textarea_id_etc"></textarea>
</div>



<p>Here is a standard text input to demo how typical validation works along with our custom ..<br />
<input type="text" name="a_standard_input" id="a_standard_input" value="" class="validate[required]" />
</p>

<p>
<input type="submit" name="b1" value="Submit this form!" />
<!-- Note:  the validation occurs when the form is submitted via submit button or javascript (not shown) -->
</p>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution: **read the validationengine documentation**
Now, say you want to prevent the form from being submitted if the text size is more than 65536 characters:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
// binds form submission and fields to the validation engine
jQuery("#newForm").validationEngine();
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#textArea").cleditor({
// cleditor options here
});
});
</script>

<form id="newForm" name="newForm" method="post" action="yourphppage.php" onSubmit="return validatesize()">
<textarea id="textArea" name="textArea"></textarea>
<input name="submit" id="button" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function validatesize() {
submitFlag=true;
if(document.newForm.textArea.value.length>65536){
    submitFlag=false;
    $("#textArea").validationEngine('showPrompt', 'Custom message', 'red', 'bottomLeft')
}
return submitFlag;
}
</script>
```

Don't forget to place the scripts in the HEAD section:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.cleditor.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.cleditor.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="validationEngine.jquery.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.validationEngine.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.validationEngine-en.js"></script>
```

Comment: To imply that the solution I posted was created without reading the documentation is ridiculous.  Your solution is primitive and performs as such.  I will stick with the accepted solution I posted.

Comment: I was not implying anything. My solution is primitively simpler and btw it works.

Comment: It does not remove the prompt once the issue that caused the prompt is corrected.  It also blindly assumes the hidden textarea is in sync with what the WYSIWYG editor is showing, which is not always the case.  So yes, it works, primitively.